# How to get a element by its property using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following is the code:

```
<td><bean:write name="row" property="suppnr" /></td>
```

How to get the supplier number (suppnr) value like below?

```
var sup = document.getElementByID('suppnr').value(); // This dosent work as suppnr is a property 
alert(sup);
```

Do we have any method to do this? Kindly help

Comment: Can you post the actual HTML that's generated, not the pre-processed template.

Comment: you're trying to get the value of `<td>`??
`$('[property="suppnr"]')` this can lead to your target but can't provide you the value.

Comment: `$('*[name="row"]').attr('property')` ?

Comment: Please check my answer with pure javascript @padmaja

Answer (score 1):

Select elements where attribute `property` exists:

```
var suppnr = $('[property]');
```

Select elements where attribute `property` equals to `suppnr`:

```
var suppnr = $('[property="suppnr"]');
```

---

```
alert (suppnr.attr('name'));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't have `ID` on `tr`, so first add `id` attribute as you are selecting via the `id` attribute.

```
<td><bean:write name="row" id="suppnr" property="suppnr" /></td>
```

Then you can easily get any attribute using `getAttribute` function:

```
var sup = document.getElementById('suppnr').getAttribute('property'); 
alert(sup);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some properties are reflections of attributes, which means that setting the property sets the attribute, which allows you to use attribute selectors. For instance, an input element's defaultValue property is a reflection of its value attribute (which its value property is not).

Otherwise, you select by what you can and use filter to filter the resulting list to only the elements you actually want.

For example, I'd set a property using jQuery like this:

```
$('#foo').prop('my-property', 'value');
```

No, there's no way to select by that property directly, you'd need something like my filter suggestion above:

```
var list = $("something-that-gets-you-close").filter(function() {
    return this["my-property"] == "value";
});
```

You might consider using data-* attributes instead:

```
$("#foo").attr("data-my-property", "value");
```

then

```
var list = $("[data-my-property='value']");
```

to select it (the inner quotes are optional for values matching the definition of a CSS identifier). Note that attribute values are always strings.

Beware: There's a persistent misconception that jQuery's data function is a simple accessor for data-* attributes. It is not. It manages a data cache associated with the element by jQuery, which is initialized from data-* attributes but disconnected from them. In particular, .data("my-property", "value") would not let you find that later via a [data-my-property=value] selector.